# ReactJS: Render Math Equation's svg in pdf

Tags: reactjs, meteor, pdf.js, katex

I am trying to render a pdf from HTML code (which includes SVG of math equations) using reactJS. I tried to use MathJax but it didn't work for me. Then, I used katex to edit and render equations in html, successfully.

```
render() {
  var txt = this.props.optionBData;
  if (txt) {
    var math = katex.renderToString(txt, {
      throwOnError: true,      
   });  
  }
  return(<span className="renderEQ" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 
   (this.props.data).replace("[EQB]",math)}}></span>);
  }
```

But I am not able to render the equations in pdf using jsPdf. [HTML render using jsPdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1igL0.png)